# Recover My account whose email address is closed

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts, account-recovery

I have created my account on stackoveflow from my company email address. link :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007076/shehzad-bilal

Now as I have left the company so my email account has been closed. How I can recover my account.

Comment: That's gonna be hard, use Contact Us at the bottom of the page to contact the SE team.